# Read wav file into python

Tags: python, audio, scipy

I'm trying to read in a wav file to run an fft on it but I keep running into an error with scipy.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav
import scipy    
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import numpy as np

rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('a1.wav')
fft_out = fft(data)
#matplotlib inline
plt.plot(data, np.abs(fft_out))
plt.show()
print 'exit'
```

The error I'm running into is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
        rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('a1.wav')
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 275, in read
        return fs, data
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
```

I thought it might have been an anaconda error so I removed anaconda but I'm still running into this issue.

If there is a better way to read wav files so that I can run ffts on them, let me know! Thanks!

Comment: which version of scipy are we talking about? Can you try the lastest one and see if the error persists

Comment: 0.18.1 (the latest) and the error still persists.

Comment: Can you try loading a different WAV file?  The problem might be specific to `a1.wav`.

Comment: Forgive me for asking: you have played this wave?

Comment: You could try running the software available at https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo to see if it exposes anything about that file.

Comment: @BillBell I can play the wav file in Audacity.

Comment: @wildilhelm you're correct, it seems to be this particular wav file. Do you know of any way to read it? Even if it's manually reading in the file?

Comment: You probably know about https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html.

Comment: Is the file the result of laboratory work?

Comment: Read then save with Audacity? And pray.

Comment: @BillBell it's a very special kind of a wav file so I need to read it as is.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the code of the particular `wavefile.read()` [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/a915b05cdfd81497507e5158a148a9187827dfc4/scipy/io/wavfile.py#L260-L264) on Github, you'll see that `data` is only set in one place in the function:

```
        elif chunk_id == b'data':
            if not fmt_chunk_received:
                raise ValueError("No fmt chunk before data")
            data = _read_data_chunk(fid, format_tag, channels, bit_depth,
                                    is_big_endian, mmap)
```

So this condition is never met when the Python interpreter runs the code, and we get the referenced before assignment exception.

A wav file consist of a header followed by a sequence of chunks. There are different types of chuncks. For example one can carry information about the data format, another the sampling rate, and then there is the one that contains the data. It seems in this case that Scipy's `read` newer encounters this `data`chunck, so it is very likely that there is something wrong with the wav file, or it might be of some newer format, which Scipy's implementation does not yet support.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be becuse you need sox package.
if so, try installing sox. `apt install sox`
Also, check the header of the audio files,

```
soxi file_1.wav
```

and

```
apt install libav-tools
apt install ffmpeg
```